# How to set Leaflet choropleth legend to always have same number of ticks

Tags: r, leaflet, r-leaflet

I'm trying export individual frames of what will ultimately be an animated gif of a ZCTA choropleth of COVID cases in NYC. I'm using a continuous shading, where the upper limit is the max value for that particular day's data (as opposed to a fixed upper limit from the data across days). The problem is that as the max(cases) changes, so do the number of ticks in the legend, which means that each frame of the gif has a legend of a different vertical size, which distracts from the shading changes on the map.

Setting "bins=X" in addLegend does *something,* but not what I want. 2 works, but I need a more granular legend. Anything greater than 2 and it looks like it still depends on the range of the data.

Here's my pallete:

```
pal <- colorNumeric(
  palette = "Blues",
  domain = c(0,max(df$new_cases_percap))
```

Here's my addPolygons:

```
addPolygons(group = "Covid",
              fillColor = ~pal(df$new_cases_percap),
              weight = 1,
              opacity = 0.7,
              color = "#333333",
              dashArray = "",
              fillOpacity = 0.75,
              highlight = highlightOptions(
                weight = 0.8,
                color = "white",
                dashArray = "",
                fillOpacity = 0.5,
                bringToFront = TRUE),
              label=labels,
              labelOptions = labelOptions(
                style = list("font-weight" = "normal", padding = "3px 8px"),
                textsize = "15px",
                direction = "auto"))
```

Here's my addLegend:

```
leaflet::addLegend("topleft", group = "Covid",pal = pal, values = c(0, max(df$new_cases_percap)), bins=4, title = paste(format(as.Date(latest_date), "%b %d"),"<br>Cumulative Confirmed Cases</strong><br>per 100,000, from Apr 1"),
                 labFormat = labelFormat(prefix = " "),
                 opacity = 1)
```

Some day's data gives me 6 ticks, and others, 5:

[6 ticks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9rep.jpg)
[5 ticks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0G1Ja.jpg)

Any direction or assistance much appreciated

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would help the community help you if you made your question reproducible; please include a minimal set of your data as an object  for example df < - data.frame (...) where ... is the data comprising variables and values. Check out [mre].